# Listing files in a folder with QListview

Tags: qt, qlistview

I tried Listing files in a folder with `QListview`. I tried using the code below but it returns this error:

> QAbstractItemView::setRootIndex failed : index must be from the
>   currently set model`

This is my code:

```
QFileSystemModel listModel;
QString directory = "/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/tmp/etc/nodes";
ui->clusterList->setRootIndex(listModel.setRootPath(directory));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have not set the view model ;

```
QFileSystemModel *listModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
QString directory = "/home/uboho/monitor_test_module/logs/tmp/etc/nodes";
ui->clusterList->setModel(listModel);
ui->clusterList->setRootIndex(listModel->setRootPath(directory));
```

Comment: Notice that I used a pointer to manage the lifetime of the model, otherwise you can use a member;

Comment: So i want to make each of the items signals, how do i do dat @Mohammad

Comment: Thats quite raw question, you might to consider a specific case.

Comment: Basically I want each of the listed item to initiate a function when clicked, the function will eventually initiate a bash script process that will generate data to be displayed in a `QTableview` Don't know if this explains better.

Comment: Yes, you have to look for `void QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index)` signal in [QAbstractItemView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#clicked).

Comment: So I can add my function to `void QAbstractItemView::clicked(const QModelIndex &index) const {}`

Comment: No, you have to use Signal/Slot model, the method above is a sgignal that Qt emits .. Signal can be connected to slots (your function).